# Why did 'r' disappear in English "speak" (compare German "sprechen") and in German "Welt" (compare English "world")?

Tags: english, historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, german, proto-germanic

I cannot help but notice some 'r'-s seem to have randomly disappeared in both German and English. What is going on there?

Comment: According to *A Historical Phonology of English by Donka Minkova* (p121): Sporadic loss of <r> occurs in some onset clusters: *sp(r)ecan* ‘to speak’, *sp(r)æċ* ‘speech’, *p(r)æˉtiġ* ‘clever, pretty’.

Comment: @"Joyful Sadness", so, the vowel in "pretty" was originally long 'ae'? So, how did it came to be short 'i'? And why was the same phenomenon, the random disappearance of 'r', occuring in German?

Comment: Since we have *worship* versus German *Wirtschaft* "economy, establishment" contrast so much, whereas *Weihe* is closer to the sliritual sense, it should be considerable if this was a case of substitution that might apply to *Werald* and *Welt* as well. Between PIE \*wer-, \*werh1-, \*swer-, etc. a reasonable mount of overlapping semantics can be infered as much as for \*wihros "man" > *were* and \*wer-(?) > *warden, warroir*, etc. (cp. further *warranty*, *promis*, Ger. *Versprechen*, *Vorsehen*... Lat. *spect-*?)

Comment: Re: why there is no r in PDE speak - we don't know why it happened. cf.  Anatoly Liberman's remark that "Despite a sizable number of pairs like speak (in Old English, specan coexisted with sprecan: cf. German sprechen), the mystery of the fugitive r has never been solved." https://blog.oup.com/2011/06/pretty-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different reasons.
'they speak/they spoke' in Protogermanic was something like 'sprekanþi/spurkun'. Note the different position of the 'r'. Our forebears made the word more regular with the Germans going for 'spr-' and '-k-'  whilst the Angles going for 'sp-' but also '-k-'.
'world' and 'Welt' are both contactions of 'weraldiz' ('men-age' or 'generation'). Contractions are always fairly irregular. The Germans and the English contracted the word slightly differently.

Comment: Disagree. Simplification of the cluster after contraction from *werald* is imaginable at least if the /r/ was a Upper German alveolar trill/flap next to the lateral approximant /l/. But about *speak*; it is attested besides *sprekan* in OE, maybe a case of different though very similar etyma like *answer* ~ Ger. *Antwort*. See, *sprek-* compares well with *spray*, whereas *speak* might compare to *spuck-* "spit" (cp. *spit it out*, Ger. *spuck's aus*, i.e. "tell me"), or *spüren* "sense" versus *Spuk* or  *fühlen* "feel" (Grimm's law applies), or PIE \*werh1- vs. \*bheh2-, etc.

Comment: @vectory It isn't surprising that both specan and sprecan existed in Old English as it will have been at that time that the regularising was happening. However I'm in good company see Kroonen, Guus "Etymological Dictionary of Proto-Germanic" (Leiden: Brill, 2013) page 469.              You are right that the simplification of /rl/ to /l/ is imaginable in German. Is it a regular sound law?

Comment: It isn't surprising? There's a hefty amount of circular reasoning and false equation in that argument. Is /rl/ > /r/ regular (in German)? Beats me. Comparing Kalle ~ Karl, Polier << Fr. parler, Berlin [bɛɐ̯ˈliːn], [bɛʁˈliːn], (Berlinisch) [bɐ̠liːn], the elision is regular where the underlying backed resonant may be elided in syllable codas, similar to rhotic vowels of AmE rather than the alveolar trill /r/ (as is reconstructed for PGem). This extends into Middle Bavarian, which is an upper German dialect coming from Middle High German, so I don't know where the /r/ can be examined.